# Will Google Play Store developer account Activity Log show me a record of uploads and key changes?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I don't currently have a developer account with the Play Store and am wondering how good the logging and alerting is for changes within such an account.  Note that I am not asking about activity logs/info that can be obtained from a mobile device on apps downloaded or services used.  As a developer, I would like to know when an upload occurs to my account and if an app signing key is uploaded or generated (among other things).  I am having trouble finding any details like this in the documentation.  Ideally, I'd like to receive an immediate alert (email or text) when certain events occur.  I'm not sure if the Activity Log is the correct feature or if there are related features.  Is this functionality present in the Play Store?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty good and it will show nearly every change happened to your app or account, with date and time and the user responsible for this change.

**here is an example of this:**

[image]

**Also Here is the data you can obtain about app signing:**

[image]

Comment: @knokej was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?